# Bootstrap carousel & Google Font Issues

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, google-fonts

I know this has been asked many times, but I still cannot seem to fix my code. As you can see, I am copied the code directly from bootstrap, and I was able to get my buttons to appear, but they are not activating. Also, google fonts was directly imported, but it too is not changing my fonts as it should. It is remaining as default.

```css
#title {
  background-color: #FF4C68;
  color: WHITE;
}
.container-fluid{
  padding: 3% 15%;
}
/* H1 FONT FAMILY NOT WORKING */
h1 {
  font-family: "Montserrat-Black";
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
h2 {
  font-family: "Montserrat-Bold";
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
h3{
  font-family: "Montserrat-Bold";
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
p{
  color: #8F8F8F;
}
body {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}
/* NAVIGATION BAR */

.navbar {
  padding-bottom: 4.5rem;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: yellow;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 0 18px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: "Montserrat-Light";
}

/* DOWNLOAD BUTTONS */
.download-button {
  margin: 5% 3% 5%;
}

/* TITLE IMAGE */
.title-image {
  width: 60%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

/* FEATURES SECTION */
#features {
  padding: 7% 15%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5%;
}
/* CHANGE PADDING ABOVE IF FIRST BODY ISNT LOOKING RIGHT */

.icon{
  color: #ef8172;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.icon:hover{
  color: #ff4c68;
}

/* TESTIMONIAL SECTION */
#testimonials {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ef8172;
  color: #fff;
}
.testimonial-img{
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
}
#press {
  background-color: #ef8172;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}
.press-logo {
  width: 15%;
  margin: 20px 20px 50px;
}
.carousel-item {
  padding: 7% 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>

  <!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;400;900&family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- CSS STYLESHEETS -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <!-- C:\Users\dparr\Downloads\TinDog-Start-master\TinDog-Start-master\css\styles.css -->

  <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/849c3de797.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <section id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid">


      <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Tindog</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </nav>


      <!-- Title -->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg download-button"><i class="fa-brands fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg download-button"><i class="fa-brands fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img class="title-image" src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>


  <!-- Features -->

  <section id="features">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="icon fa-solid fa-circle-check fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
        <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="icon fa-solid fa-bullseye fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
        <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="icon fa-solid fa-heart fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
        <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>


  <!-- Testimonials -->

  <section id="testimonials">

    <div id="#testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false" data-pause="hover">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-img" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
          <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
          <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>







  </section>


  <!-- Press -->

  <section id="press">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/techcrunch.png" alt="tc-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/tnw.png" alt="tnw-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/bizinsider.png" alt="biz-insider-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/mashable.png" alt="mashable-logo">

  </section>


  <!-- Pricing -->

  <section id="pricing">

    <h2>A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
    <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>


    <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
    <h2>Free</h2>
    <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
    <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>


    <h3>Labrador</h3>
    <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
    <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
    <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>


    <h3>Mastiff</h3>
    <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
    <p>Pirority Listing</p>
    <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
    <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>

  </section>


  <!-- Call to Action -->

  <section id="cta">

    <h3>Find the True Love of Your Dog's Life Today.</h3>
    <button type="button">Download</button>
    <button type="button">Download</button>

  </section>


  <!-- Footer -->

  <footer id="footer">

    <p>© Copyright TinDog</p>

  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove # in the carousel ID `id="testimonial-carousel"` and everything will work
Also set the font style like this `font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;`

```css
/* TESTIMONIAL SECTION */
#testimonials {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ef8172;
  color: #fff;
}
.testimonial-img{
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
}
#press {
  background-color: #ef8172;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}
.press-logo {
  width: 15%;
  margin: 20px 20px 50px;
}
.carousel-item {
  padding: 7% 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/849c3de797.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <!-- Testimonials -->

  <section id="testimonials">

    <div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false" data-pause="hover">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-img" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
          <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
          <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: See my answer [and mark it if it helped you.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

**1. What exactly is wrong with the buttons? Carousel**

[Read how to connect the 5 Budstrap correctly](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/)

The scripts should be plugged at the very bottom, before `</body>`

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**2. Connecting fonts**

html:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

css:

```
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight: 900;
```